# Can these similarities between PIE and Burushaski be explained?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, reconstruction

We have:

```
English     PIE         Burushaski

brown       bʰerH-om    baard-um
tongue      dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s   juŋus
warm        gʷʰer-om    gar-um
pair        kʷeth₂      kaat
fire        péh₂wr̥      pʰu
```

Some sources give `fooh` for fire in Burushaski. The endings in Burushaski are also given as -um or -om.

Comment: this is methodologically backwards. The null hypothesis is that any similarities are coincidental, and the burden of proof is on the person arguing for a relationship to demonstrate that they cannot be

Comment: This are just 5 random words not showing any regular correspondence at all (all exhibiting different initial segments, to start with).

Comment: @SirCornflakes endings seem the same in 3 cases.

Comment: @Anixx ? I don't see corresponding endings (apart from the two -om's tentatively sparated from their roots).

Comment: Given Burushaski’s geographic location, it would hardly be surprising if at least some of these were borrowings from Indo-Aryan languages (or other Indo-European languages in the area) – we know that there are many such loans in Burushaski. _Garom_ in particular looks suspiciously close to forms like Sanskrit _gháram_. Also, if Wikipedia’s list of Burushaski vocabulary correspondences is anything to go by, some of these are just plain wrong. ‘Tongue’, for example, is given as [juˈumus] in all variants, which looks completely unrelated. And what is _*kʷeth₂_? I’ve never seen that before.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet one of the variants in Wikitionary is ju'uŋus and I think j here means /đ/

Comment: You’re right, I missed that one. Still, given that all the other forms have [m], Occam’s razor would assume that that is the original phoneme. I don’t know what your ⟨đ⟩ is supposed to represent, but [j] in the Wikipedia article represents IPA [j], the semivowel found in English _yes_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *kʷeth₂ has come up a few times here before when Nostratic claims (and similar) have been discussed. Afaik the main claimed reflex in PIE (as opposed to the other purported Nostratic languages long range comparativists tend to draw upon when discussing this) is as the stem of *kʷetwóres which would then be derived by applying plural endings to what was originally a dual form (but no longer interpretable as such when the root was displaced by the more familiar *dw-)

Comment: @Tristan I meant this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/%C4%8Deta and yes, I think *kʷetwóres comes from this root as well, along with Latin clitic -kʷe (interestingly, in Burushaski there is a similar clitic -kaat, meaning the same as in Latin).

Comment: @Anixx note that the root there is given as *kʷet- (which would also fit *kʷetwóres better), and the nouns as *kʷeteh₂. *kʷeth₂ is not suggested anywhere that I can see. Getting *-kʷe from this root is trickier as PIE seems to have allowed final -t, so we wouldn't expect it to have dropped. I guess you could posit an irregular reduction in the clitic though

Comment: also note that that claimed root in the wiktionary entry is unsourced

Comment: @Tristan kaa or ka meant "with" in Burushaski. https://www.webonary.org/burushaski-hunza/browse/browse-vernacular/?letter=k&key=bsk-Latn-x-orthogra ; https://glosbe.com/fo/bsk/og

Comment: @Anixx I was only talking about the Slavic and PIE in my last two comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A genetic relation between Burushaski and IE has been argued by Ilija Çasule (Macquarie University). This is not as yet widely accepted, but it is worthy of serious discussion and not simply rejected on dogmatic grounds. The question is complicated by the fact that B. has lots of loanwords from Indo-Aryan and Iranian.

Comment: Do these particular words (for instance, the word for tongue) belong to his hypothesized cognates or they are I-A borrowings?

Comment: @Anixx: Look up his article in Joutnal of Indo-Europesn Studies, Volume 40, Number 1 & 2, Spring/Summer 2012.

Comment: Found this: https://www.academia.edu/44781358/Burushaski_etymological_dictionary He apparently outright argues that Burushaski is an IE language, which seems too much for me (for instance, totally different numerals (except for one) exclude this possibility for me).

Comment: Well, yes, he links all the proposed words except the one for pair to PIE, and exactly to the ones I suggested. But his PIE  reconstructions are uncommon (no laryngeals etc), so I think, this is not mainstream.

Answer (score -1):

It's the semantics of "tongue" that make this liable for transmission by oral tradition.

- "brown" is too general. You need to know what brown connotes, to exclude connections with eg. *bear*.
- One could by the same tokan compare *Dolgan* per se, a Turkic language related to Yakut, comparing *tell*, Dutch *taal* "language" etc.

  For example, Tocharian has *kom* "sun" as Turkic isogloss, eg. Yakut күн (kün).
- θερμός et al. don't make for the simple kind of soundchange that would make *gar-um* the most likely expected outcome. /g/ is prevalent in Indo-Iranian reflexes only, so this indicative of a loan, one-way or another.

  A pro-pos FIRE I won't miss a beat to remark on Blažek's treatment of IE Smiths. Suffice to say it begins with Indic *karaman* vel sim.
- Is **kʷeth₂* maybe related to i. Lat. *quatro* ii. TochA. *kät* (to spread, scatter, sow), or thematically simpler to compare from PIE **wi-* "apart, separate"?
- In **péh₂wr̥*, **-wr̥* may be regarded as a suffix, but then it's not clear what the root would symbolize. It contrasts as common noun with the root of *ignite*, but not so for example in English. As a loan it might belong either to culture, religion and industry, or the household.

  It is remarkable that final does not match at the syllable end while rounding should indicate presence of the tail end if it was related.

Comment: In*péh₂wr̥ the suffix is -r.